# IBM Worklight 6.1. Adapters. SSL working with worklight.properties but not with Liberty SSL configuration

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have read the posts that are about this subject but I have not found any one that helps me.

I have an adapter that invokes a service using HTTPS.

It works if I do the SSL configuration using the server/conf/worklight.properties file with the properties: (after importing the backend server certificate in the default.keystore)

```
ssl.keystore.path=conf/default.keystore
ssl.keystore.type=jks
ssl.keystore.password=worklight
```

But if I comment those properties and edit the server.xml with this configuration:

```
<feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
<keyStore id="worklight" location="${server.config.dir}/default.keystore" password="worklight"/>
```

The adapter does not work and fails with the error:

```
Http request failed: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
```

The "${server.config.dir}/default.keystore" file and "conf/default.keystore" file are the same file.

Is it possible to invoke https services from adapters in the Worklight Studio Liberty Profile Server without using the worklight.properties file and making the SSL configuration directly in the server.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worklight is not seeking SSL certificates in liberty key store. If the certificate is selfsigned it should be added to the keystore defined into worklight.properties or into default OS/JVM keystore.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I understand this is only for Liberty, if Worklight is installed over a WebSphere Application Server (not Liberty profile) the SSL configuration of WAS will be used and there is no need to configure the OS/JVM keystores. Is this right?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is the same behaviour on WAS server.
WL works only with default JVM keystore and the WL keystore.